# Is "also" necessary in the construction: not only because ... but (also) because ...?

Tags: sentence-construction

I always thought that also was necessary in constructions like this.

But then I saw this line from The Wind-Up Bird Chronicles by Haruki Murakami:

> I wanted to ignore the phone, **not only because** the spaghetti was
>   nearly done, **but because** Claudio Abbado was bringing the London
>   Symphony to its musical climax.

So maybe it's okay to leave "also" out in this type of structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific example, I would say it is fine to leave it out - duplication of any word in English tends to sound odd, however if this was something similar, in something along the lines of a user-manual, then the repetition does make the intent slightly clearer.

If you don't like the repetition, but do want the clarity, then any true synonym of `also`, such as `additionally`, would fit just as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you are putting up another reason. So it has to be also, or any other word that adds, like additionally, or furthermore. But in this context, also would be the one word that fits.